# Trouble moving div down

Tags: html, css

Im sure this is very simple but i have been looking at this for a while today and just cant figure it out.

All i want to do is move the top div '#template-nav' down a little bit so there is some white space above it. I have tried margin-top and padding but it just wont move down.

I have the jsfiddle below along with the code, be really grateful to find out where i have gone wrong here.

https://jsfiddle.net/rufusbear/Lgx7eksa/

```
<div id="template">
  <div class="template-row">
    <div id="template-nav"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="template-row">
    <div id="template-jumbo"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="template-row">
    <div class="template-col-1"></div>
    <div class="template-col-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="template-row">
    <div id="template-footer"></div>
  </div>


</div>

#template {
  background: #fff;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.template-row {
  max-width: 380px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#template-nav {
  height: 40px;
  background: #8dcdc1;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#template-jumbo {
  height: 150px;
  margin: 2% 0%;
  background: #d3e397;
}

.template-col-1 {
  height: 130px;
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2%;
  background: #fff5c3;
}

.template-col-2 {
  height: 130px;
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2%;
  background: #fff5c3;
}

#template-footer {
  height: 40px;
  margin: 2% 0%;
  background: #d3e397;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: '.';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Thanks all

Comment: Try this https://jsfiddle.net/Lgx7eksa/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a margin-top to that top element inside `#template` won't work, since the margins of the element and its top child influence each other.
But you can add a `padding-top`to `#template`:

https://jsfiddle.net/wh6cgLt0/

Comment: Oh right i see!! I cant believe i missed that. I was adding the padding to the wrong element all along!! Thank you so much really appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

```
#template {
  background: #fff;
  width: 400px;
  margin-top: 10%;
 /* removed height property */
  padding: 10px 0; /* adds padding to top and bottom evenly */
}
```

Just a basic CSS edit....

[Fiddle update](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/Lgx7eksa/8/)

Comment: Oh right i see!! I cant believe i missed that. I was adding the padding to the wrong element all along!! Thank you so much really appreciate that